# How can I find an inverse function of solution from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, inverse

I have the following code.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 
 3 x'[t] Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] + Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]]) == 0, 
 a'[t]/a[t] == Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4],
 τ'[t] == 1/a[t],
 x'[0] == -0.008226306418212731,
 x[0] == 5.630991866033891,
 a[0] == 1,
 τ[149.4517772937791] == 0},
 {x, τ, a},
 {t, 0, 500}]
```

I want to get the inverse function of `τ[t]` from the `NDSolve` solution. However, the usual `Inverse` function does not work for this example. Any idea how I might solve it?

Also, I have a list `tRange=Range[0,500,0.01]`, is it possible to substitute these values into the inverse function? If so, how?

Comment: You need `InverseFunction`, not `Inverse`. For example, `invx = InverseFunction[x] /. sol[[1]]` should give you an inverse function for `x`: `invx[5.546]`

Comment: Actually, there is no inverse for `t > 104.99154906374548`, because `τ` is constant thereafter with value `-1.6349260051421602*^-7`.